# Free Text Mining Corpora of News Articles and Headlines

Tags: text-mining

Is there any corpus available for free based on News Articles and Headlines?

I am looking for areas where I can do text mining and analysis for which I need a corpus of related data.

Where can I freely download them?

Comment: Freely, as in "free beer"? If so, I think you're out of luck. And even if you or your research group are part of the [LDC](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/), freely as in "freely licensed" (but at a cost) doesn't exist either, AFAIK. News are difficult to distribute freely due to very restrictive licensing terms and authorship rights. You're probably best off scraping that data yourself, honestly... But I'll be glad to be proven wrong!

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the ambiguity. I actually meant open source. !

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for SO. However, there is at least one dataset that comes to mind: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/reuters-21578+text+categorization+collection

Comment: Aww - right, Reuters-21578 is freely licensed for research purposes at least... Good point[er]!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this type of question is off-topic for SO but since I know about a good dataset that might be of your interest, I am sharing the information.

**[Newyork Times 2013 (NYT2013)](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/luwang/)**

- New York Times, CNN, and BBC news articles and user comments on four major events happened in 2014.
- New York Times news articles and user comments in 2013.

Used in the work - [Socially-Informed Timeline Generation for Complex Events](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/luwang/papers/NAACL2015.pdf). Dataset can be downloaded from [here](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/luwang/datasets/socialtimeline.zip).